# How to add command to right-click menu of certain extension programmatically?

Tags: c++, qt

I have created 2 exe files:  open.exe and edit.exe. and a new extension: say .newext.

Now I want to

1. open by double click on .newext file with open exe.
2. get a menu with right click on .newext file where in bold it is written "Open" and under that it is written "Edit". And by clicking "Edit" the edit.exe opens the .newext file.
3. do this programmatically so that it could work on as much platforms as it is possible 
   (at least on Xp, Vista, and Win7).

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must edit the classes tree in the registry (using the registry functions from `AdvApi32.dll`). The following is not tested and off my head:

- The base key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` for system-wide settings and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` for user-specific settings
- In this base key, create a subkey with name `.newext` and default value *X*, where *X* is the class name (an arbitrary string that uniquely identifies the file type)
- In the base key, create a subkey with name *X* and default value *Y*, where *Y* is the user-visible description of the file type
- In the key *X*, create a subkey named `shell` with default value `open`
- In the `shell` key, create a subkey named `open` with default value `&Open`
- In the `open` key, create a subkey named `command` with default value `"C:\path\to\open.exe" "%1"`
- In the `shell` key, create a subkey named `edit` with default value `&Edit`
- In the `edit` key, create a subkey named `command` with default value `"C:\path\to\edit.exe" "%1"`

Comment: On Linux the system is completely different and depends on the desktop environment (Gnome, KDE…). It might be better to start a new question for every desktop environment you plan to support (preferably on superuser.com since it's not really related to programming).

Comment: Try it, I'm not sure and I don't have access to Vista.